# Ligar LED via USB

Tags: c#

Como posso enviar um pulso de 5V através de uma USB?

Imagine um cabo USB que tem 4 fios (um gera 5V e o outro polo negativo). 
Sobram os dois fios centrais. Minha duvida está como posso ler via Delphi que estes cabos estão recebendo 5V?

**Objetivo**: Capturar sinal para contagem de unidades via Serial.

**Ideia**: Através de um cabo USB abrir uma tranca elétrica.

O programa que estou desenvolvendo enviaria um pulso de 5V. A ideia seria ligar esse pulso a um dos cabos USB.

**Dúvida**:

1. Como posso enviar um pulso de 5v via cabo USB?
2. Com relação ao envio: Em C# como ligar e desligar um LED via USB. Porque ligar direto é fácil usando energia normal do USB.

Comment: Boa pergunta, também estou querendo resolver isso. =X

Comment: Estou a muito tempo atrás de uma resposta para essa pergunta.

Comment: @JulioSantos tem algum código pra facilitar uma possivel resposta?

Comment: Talvez o livro "USB Explained", do Steven McDowell (editora Prentice-Hall), possa lhe ajudar a resolver seu problema. Apesar de não passar código-fonte, nele você encontra detalhes sobre a especificação do protocolo USB.

Comment: Entendo que este problema é de eletrônica e não de programação. E a parte de programação vai depender do tipo de chip que for ligado ao USB, pois não dá pra controlar de maneira consistente o USB como fazíamos com portas paralelas, pois USB é um canal de comunicação e não de controle direto - diferente de portas paralelas que, por sua vez, já tem a eletrônica de controle embutida na especificação.

Comment: Um ano depois do comentário anterior vejo que algumas respostas, apesar de corretas, mais complicam do que ajudam. Extremamente exagerado usar um Arduino pra uma tarefa que um adaptador paralelo de 10 reais resolveria. E o adaptador ja vem particamente pronto pra usar, só usar um driverzinho simples pra não puxar corrente excessiva da paralela e pronto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vamos por partes...

O USB (*Universal Serial Bus*) é um protocolo de comunicação serial utilizado para realizar comunicação entre periféricos, considerando que um periférico é composto por um "centro de processamento" é errôneo realizar a ativação de um LED apenas enviando um sinal via D+ e D-. A grosso modo o LED não sabe ler comandos que chegam via conexão serial.

Você pode utilizar plataformas de prototipagem eletrônica, entre elas se destaca o Arduino.

Basicamente o que você faria seria desenvolver e compilar um código para Arduino onde nesse código você receberia comando do seu programa (C#, Delphi, C++) via USB e ativaria os atuadores como LED, Reles e etc...

Você pode aprender mais sobre em:

http://www.arduino.cc/ e 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLd_JyvKV4Y

Tenho disponível também meu tema de conclusão de curso que mostra um modelo de desenvolvimento comercial com Arduino.

http://siaibib01.univali.br/pdf/Lucas%20Alves%20Selliach.pdf

**Um exemplo:**

Digamos que você quer realizar o acendimento de um LED X período de tempo utilizando um Arduino, você pode utilizar esse código:

```
/ * 
   Acende um LED por um segundo, então fora por um segundo, repetidamente. 
   Este exemplo de código é de domínio público. 
* /

void setup () 
{
   // Inicializa o pino digital como uma saída.
   // Pin 13 tem um LED conectado na maioria das placas Arduino:
   pinMode (13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop () 
{
   digitalWrite (13, HIGH); / / set o LED
   delay (1000); / esperar / por um segundo
   digitalWrite (13, LOW); / / definir o off LED
   delay (1000); / esperar / por um segundo
}
```

Comment: Links futuramente podem quebrar, poste ao menos um exemplo aqui por favor :)

Answer (score 6):

**Não por que...**

você não pode fazer isso de uma forma "Bonita", uma solução seria desligar e ligar a saída USB, mas tenho quase certeza que SO não vai deixar você fazer isso assim tão fácil.

USB é totalmente dedicada a passagem de informação, mas no cabo você encontra saídas +5V e GND para alimentação dos dispositivos plugados.

**Controlando um dispositivo eletrônico por programação**

Primeiramente você precisa entender eletrônica, pelo menos o minimo (corrente,resistência..etc)
você pode usar um microcontrolador ou um circuito capaz de se comunicar com computador, hoje em dia o **Arduíno** se tornou a plataforma mais fácil e de simples implementação de projetos para desenvolvedores leigos, arduino pode ser programado em java,c,python sendo c a forma adotada pela comunidade.

Imprimindo dados na saída Serial

```
int pushButton = 2;
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // informa que pino "2" é uma entrada de dados
  pinMode(pushButton, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // faz a leitura da saida "2" do dispositivo 
  int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);
  // Mostra isso na saida Serial
  Serial.println(buttonState);
  delay(1);
}
```

Você pode fazer seu programa se comunicar com outro através da porta serial.

**Comunicação Arduino com porta serial em python**

Python é uma linguagem com muitas facilitações, existe modulo para praticamente qualquer coisa, inclusive para arduino, web, interfaces...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
 Blinks an LED on digital pin 13
 in 1 second intervals
"""

from Arduino import Arduino
import time

board = Arduino('9600') #plugged in via USB, serial com at rate 9600
board.pinMode(13, "OUTPUT")

while True:
    board.digitalWrite(13, "LOW")
    time.sleep(1)
    board.digitalWrite(13, "HIGH")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Confira a documentação [Python-Arduino](https://github.com/thearn/Python-Arduino-Command-API)

Answer (score 1):

Um aoutra opcao é utilizar a porta serial Comx da seguinte forma
usando o pino 4 (DTR)
no antigo DOS seria
mode Com1 dtr=off/on

Conector db9
Pino 4=DTR Pino 5 GND
Via software acionando o pino 4
ligar resistor em serie com o led
tipo  4---xxxx----led-----5
no antigo DOS (janela)
Mode Com2 dtr=ON  >>> liga o led
              OFF >>> deslga o led

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao site. Você pode detalhar mais a resposta? Tem um link [edit] nela. Sua ideia é ligar o led direto num dos pinos da serial? Tem como chavear  o 5V nesse pino por software?